# Convert from java.util.Vector to a scala Seq

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I can see that there are ways to convert from a Java list to a Scala seq (using `asScala` method) but I could not find any converters for `java.util.Vector`.

Is there a similar way for this conversion too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`JavaConverters` is a bit more idiomatic than `JavaConversions`.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val v = new java.util.Vector[Int]
val s: Seq[Int] = v.asScala
```

Answer (score 3):

Import `JavaConversions`:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

val v = new java.util.Vector[Int]()
val s = v.toSeq
// s is of type Seq[Int]
```

Comment: `JavaConversions` is so awful that the kind of thing it does is not behind warnings on Scala 2.10.0. Use it if it is to your tastes, but, please, do not recommend it.

Comment: @Daniel, I didn't realize there were better alternatives. Always good to learn new things. Thanks!

Comment: @daniel, 'Programming In Scala' only discusses JavaConversions and the 2.10 nightly docs still say "The JavaConversions object provides implicit defs that will allow mostly seamless integration between Java Collections-based APIs and the Scala collections library." Plus there are a number of classes/traits that seem to be related: JavaConversions, JavaConverters, DecorateAsJava, DecorateAsScala, WrapAsJava, WrapAsScala. Is there a 'HowTo' anywhere that describes what current best practice is?

Comment: @AlanBurlison I've never looked around for one. I'll see if I can get the scaladoc to warn against using JavaConversions.

Comment: There's also WrapAsJava and DecorateAsJava, which makes four different packages that seem to do the same sort of thing. It's just a little bit confusing... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that starting `Scala 2.13`, the package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) provides [`asScala`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html#asScala[A](l:java.util.List[A]):scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[A]) via a pimp of `java.util.List` and replaces packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val javaVector = new java.util.Vector(java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
javaVector.asScala.toSeq
// Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```